# RestKit .20 RKRequestDescriptor postObject - Expected status code in (400-499), got 200

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Having a bit of a strange problem, I'm using RestKit to post a CoreData object to a remote web service. Everything on the remote end looks to be working fine but it seems like RestKit is having some issues mapping the response.

My object response mappings look like this, I have a User class with a UserProfile one to one relationship:

```
 //UserProfile
 RKEntityMapping * userProfileMapping =
        [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([UserProfile class])
                            inManagedObjectStore:[manager managedObjectStore]];
//…mapping
//User
RKEntityMapping * userMapping =
        [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([User class])
                            inManagedObjectStore:[manager managedObjectStore]];

//…mapping

//relationship mapping
[userMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping 
     relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"userProfile"
                          toKeyPath:@"userProfile"
                        withMapping:userProfileMapping]];

 //add the response mappings for GET success
 [manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[
        [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                     method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                pathPattern:nil
                                                    keyPath:@"currentUser"
                     statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]] …rest of my mappings];
```

The request mapping is the inverse of `userMapping`

```
  RKRequestDescriptor * currentUserRequestDescriptor =
            [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[userMapping inverseMapping]
                                                  objectClass:[User class]
                                                  rootKeyPath:@"currentUser"
                                                       method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

  [manager addRequestDescriptor:currentUserRequestDescriptor];
```

My `GET` requests on the `User` class are working fine, `POST` is also working correctly.

To update my `User` coreData object I'm using `postObject'

```
[objectManager postObject:updatedUser
                     path:@"update"
               parameters:nil
                  success:…handler
                  failure:…handler]
```

The `POST` works correctly and the object is saved in my remote service. 
However, my `success` handler is never called and I never get the updated `User` object. I have logging on and I see the valid JSON in the response.

```
response.body={"currentUser":{….user object}}
```

Instead, failure is called, it seems to want a 400 response instead of the 200 my service is responding with.

"NSLocalizedDescription" -> "Expected status code in (400-499), got 200"

I don't see a way to set the expected statusCodes on `RKRequestDescriptor` like on `RKResponseDescriptor`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your User response descriptor uses `method:RKRequestMethodGET` so it won't be considered as a match for the response from your POST request.

Instead, set the `method` to `RKRequestMethodAny`.

Presumably RestKit is expecting a 400-499 because you have a response descriptor configured to handle error responses at that path.